# Typescript - How to dynamically type an object with keys from a dynamic array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that reduces an array of properties and builds an object:

```js
type FieldProps = {
  name: string;
  value: string;
  required: boolean;
  styles?: object;
  className?: string
}

const fields: FieldProps[] = [
  {
    name: "firstName",
    value: "Bob",
    required: true,
    styles: { width: "100%"}
  },
  {
    name: "lastName",
    value: "Smith",
    required: true,
    className: "example"
  },
  {
    name: "city",
    value: "Tulsa",
    required: true,
  },
  {
    name: "state",
    value: "OK",
    required: true,
  },
]

const parseFields = <T extends any[], K extends object = {}>(fields: T): K => {
  try {
    if (!fields || (fields && fields.length < 0)) throw new Error("You must supply an array of fields!");

    const parsedFields = fields.reduce((acc, { name, value }: { name: string, value: string}) => {
      switch (name) {
        case "city":
        case "street":
        case "state":
        case "suite":
        case "zipCode": {
          acc["address"] = acc["address"] || {};
          if (value) acc.address[name] = value;
          break;
        }
        default: {
          acc[name] = value;
          break;
        }
      }
      return acc;
    }, {} as K);

    return parsedFields;
  } catch (err) {
    throw String(err);
  }
};

const userDetails = parseFields(fields);
```

As of now, hovering over `userDetails` is displaying an empty object **type**(`{}`), when it ideally should be:

```
{
  "firstName": string,
  "lastName": string,
  "address": {
    "city": string,
    "state": string
  }
}
```

How can I refactor the function to take the type `FieldProps[]` and have it return a dynamically typed object?

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglhANgEwAoCcD2YDOUC8UA3gFBRQB2AhgLYQBcUOw6cFA5gNxlQBuViAK4MmLNlx7oIAR0FwpyRgCNMmRBCoVu5ZiHU4A-I0xKAVhADGwbVAuIqOHADlaEI6NYcSAXxIkLmBTMUABmCCg4jPBIaFi4ANoAugRQ8Tyk5OTUdIwARGHozC50uQA0POT8QiK5AEImZRVQUrLyEIpQLMLlmaJ6EJHEUADucMjAABZ5AIwADLMApLm+5N49xE3ZNfZFro29VcJ5AMo0cJP7mS1yCoxdEOvkdg7OrnkQAB60YOq5PGvpTZvKC5CznECXSoCI4ggAqgkQOCokOaMhu7Tu6G6-3WGUyWzyzCowAgKMONQA8gBpFHXNode7rAGJPwBILAKBgKiFCDRCIpAA8sKgnxJFGQeE0ICSpSgVJFHzFEqgJnMVhSRG8AD4ABRhGKDWEASkY8vwWo25BYIEtmTgISgOoAhPr+QAfN2O13KgBkPtC4QlADp1BxJlABVBZkajZ0JlhhpQIImAKLoLDoHW5ACamEEUBogmCOEEYB+Ns0UG56CoNswDu9OCduSN3CabOCXJ5yD5ysIjaDCkEFggOp1VAsFllREorll5Kg3kYM4JHnE8+hImYnnY3lj5ttvRwo2AFgmjq2sbxvSeDmgoPBuXoTV6FjvIO3EAgwCfL8yb5we8iRJX8b3-d9chLc5SWfMDb0AkEAC84DAABhTBkBgw84InCx4lyKhkGQKRHFyZJCFw-DCOIgYcDIqAPWIbwbDgqB7UdclY1woNqJInB4i2ci+E3Fi4KUKQqAAa1E3oVjgzCQioBFgGXP9ekowSUnJGSb3EjRpLUxc-zk3opGAQR0AoKtJ1EtYmKrPAqVbPxTO-CyrK7QCe0DHAbG8WxiTPR0IHTK8mkmBMoGOMQOB1EL0Gc1YfDbDsOSLEKABFvyoOBERSTzeR8vUfOcjs1AgENMHYHV0vQLLgByxEjT8AB6AAqHhQEgZAVVLQQORwCY8xQKAlAYMhr3yeRdhKRht3XCpch2YBiiw+aOEeAiiL4p9sJBMFQF29b2EechIIakC5pi9gKjk3w2paoA)

---

#### Update

It's super close to being typed with the help of @Mingwei, but I'd essentially like to return the `typeof ParseFieldsResult<T>`. For example, I tweaked his [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglhANgEwAoCcD2YDOUC8UA3gFBRQB2AhgLYQBcUOw6cFA5gNxlQBuViAK4MmLNlx7oIAR0FwpyRgCNMmRBCoVu5ZiHU4A-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-jisAUBgAxTEluqCGbtubYdhQXY9iWGDYYOf5sohzathBjGYSxsHwSCQ5DgAFGEFmrgAlIw7n4COqIsN2tJTouwUAIRhRE+oGqFzFQOJkkZaW6bqBwAxQLWUAjBFEX1P0WBdJQEANX66BYOgwXJAAmpgghQDQgjBJiYDPN2mgiq1VDdj+hU4KlyQRZKzQBEExmmYWyC+aOM3pgoggWBAwXBcGFh-rurh-nih41bFJHNDgPTABY-RQMFiw1UlS0ONAPx-Mk9AVJ9jHfEaEAmn9APxBYX3A8ATI4v9zSA99mJ7PDEOXNDyROq67rw7diPkMdUTJARmnJMKhBEyTGlEeTWXEN4NgE+QcApXiNXHempNEVEiwingX4-mBP6c9zjgUzGhRM8zSioTO0vNNMzMeiEVBVh06PxETfOioLi7C4ux0S5doqaCACuI7LGjy5rSuKxDUjAII6CUcd0uzAz-NQGyC1+M0jvO5RwVrYxG3Mb7My2EyT0vQ+6DvRUAz1VAWxiBwwVxxHh4+JKy3BAND4ACImlQcAQqOIfmREOUWb7YFQAAWqOBvJox6DF7DZc4NwPr1Nmjd4SQvfNGLxGkMPzPaiAQlpxIE8E5aIjCXpQ++orPe+hJ8zz6E8grEkulz2v8TLMAmRL7PG-Z0AA) and I'd like to return the `typeof O`. What's silly is that if I copy & move the type `ParseFieldsResult<T>` into the return, then it gives me the object type I'd expect see on `userDetails` (but with WET code): [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglhANgEwAoCcD2YDOUC8UA3gFBRQB2AhgLYQBcUOw6cFA5gNxlQBuViAK4MmLNlx7oIAR0FwpyRgCNMmRBCoVu5ZiHU4A-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-jisAUBgAxTEluqCGbtubYdhQXY9iWGDYYOf5sohzathBjGYSxsHwSCQ5DgAFGEFmrgAlB0PAEZp0XNNJ04BkGVi1gpPlKax1b8WpcoaUR2krrpEgzD4UCSaiiWUa+Qjyd55nQVlqmBepvFafxOnCXpZX4COqIsN2tJTouwUAIRhRE+oGqFzHlZJE2lum6gcAMUC1lAIwRRF9T9FgXSUBA+1+ugWDoMFyQAJqYIIUA0IIwSYmAzzdpoIonVQ3Y-gtOCjckEWSs0ARBMZpmFsgvmjt96YKIIFgQMFwXBhYf67q4f54oe229SRzQ4D0wAWP0UDBYs21DYDDjQD8fzJPQFQU4x3xGhAJq0-T8QWJTTPAEyOJ080DNU5iex8+zlxc8kTquu6fM4wL5BI1EySxURyTCoQivK-ljhq1NxDeDY8vkHAI14ttSPpirjhRIsIp4F+P5gT+FtWzg6sxoUhtG0oqEzl7zTTEbHohFQVbxUbCsWBYNuuHb-7fouTuLkj7sY6KmggP7As+xofti4e7OB80UjAII6CUUjXuzPrcdsv9fjFyaZeUcFoOMeDzH1zMthMoTxMPugZMVAMe1QFsYgcMFA9dwXBt+EDwT3Q+AAiJpUHAEKjm3DWljNFn1z69TZlAABaeEkIfzSu9Fl9G9qIBCRPEi3-LloiF1z++gH3CHxJ8wv6EeQKwkjFR-l-eIyxgCZHfk-MBBcgA).

Comment: When I run the code in the playground, I get the first desired output. TypeScript doesn't do runtime type checking...

Comment: I don't see a return type defined and TypeScript is not going to generate it automatically. Something like `const userDetails: MyReturnType = parseFields(fields)` should do the trick and TypeScript can then validate that `parseFields` returns a `MyReturnType`.

Comment: I'm referring to hovering over `userDetails` and seeing the shape of the object returned by `parseFields`.

Comment: My goal is to dynamically generate a type on the returned object from the array keys (specifically from  the `name` and `value` object properties within the array).

Comment: It's possible to do but not simple. Also you will have to change the type of `fields` to `as const`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is very (over)complicated, but you do end up with this type:

```
const userDetails = parseFields(fields);
type Z = typeof userDetails;
// type Z = {
//     address: {
//         city: "Tulsa" | "Norman"; // Added to test
//         state: "OK";
//     };
// } & {
//     firstName: "Bob";
//     lastName: "Smith";
// }
```

It requires making `fields` `as const`:

```
const fields = [
  ...
] as const;
```

And... the actual typings:

```
type AddressKeys = 'city' | 'street' | 'state' | 'suite' | 'zipCode';

type _ParseFieldsResultKeys<T extends readonly FieldProps[]> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends { name: string } ? T[K]['name'] : never;
}[Exclude<keyof T, keyof []>];

type _GetParseFieldResultValue<T extends readonly FieldProps[], N> =
  Extract<T[keyof T], { name: N }> extends { value: infer V } ? V : never;

type ParseFieldsResult<T extends readonly FieldProps[]> = {
  address: {
    [N in Extract<_ParseFieldsResultKeys<T>, AddressKeys>]: _GetParseFieldResultValue<T, N>;
  }
} & {
  [N in Exclude<_ParseFieldsResultKeys<T>, AddressKeys>]: _GetParseFieldResultValue<T, N>;
};

const parseFields = <T extends readonly FieldProps[]>(fields: T): ParseFieldsResult<T> => {
```

It's probably not a good idea to use this. But: [**Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglhANgEwAoCcD2YDOUC8UA3gFBRQB2AhgLYQBcUOw6cFA5gNxlQBuViAK4MmLNlx7oIAR0FwpyRgCNMmRBCoVu5ZiHU4A-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-sDwZQEZwUYAaiz44n7snU1J05ns-e82wHBCwPJwS3wHg1xYKgrHjKIdz3ZsD17L4nEHEtO27Yg+BZRg2BCBcoGfQdhyIqAZznBdz2lW8cCDXNw0jRBgHfTDvw0DMKCzHMQwwICT1LVF0wVNp2jLeIojQ6soPQGCWL9AM6IAxin2YmMcHjIsDzlESlRVHBT0YH1r2AWj6JDR8XzfEFQKLGxfCHAAycTJKrCgoDXDctwUu8GMstT9M07T5UVHB1MMqBjJvRTzIfJjgFfQp41spcJQCIJgCgMAYuU0tWM-Lt2N-Lj-1zPiC2LAAKMIQzEkEAEpGDM5T-JYkFwJLVEWGzakq0bSqAEIaoiPV9WqhioEc5zhtDAA6dQOAGKBYygEZ6vq+p+iwLpKAgHaV3QLB0Eq5IAE1MEEKAaEEYInzAZ5s00YVDqobM9xmnABuSeqJWadLgmywNkFywgPtmhRBAsCBKsqmCLGQyhXAPHFBw2-BOoqHQemACx+igSrFg23q-ocaAfj+ZJ6Ex+ILFJ75DQgY1Kepy46bpYAGSZKnmhJuj6ZtLmWdsNnHRdN0ufEnn4jhqJkmE0LkiFQgZblkLRMV0biG8GwpfIOB+pxDa4dm+XRKiRZhTwBDG29PdjdNxwlZwwpLeFCgQB13WlB-GtPeaaZdfdEIqCjDohfIGWLZFa36gvO2LAsJ2UZFTQPfDqBvY0X2hYD-3qakYBBHQdy4c92Ytdd5q-PizSfr8ZoC6L9zAbo4GGPs4WcbxyqF3QImKgGbaoC2MQOB7w665mHw0rFTKboXAARY0qDgCFSxb2LQ3G2q6+9KAAC1S1txt5-QJeOdXnBuAAemv2PpUPwhSFvnmHbE5+7912w-hSMEIShO0yQ8QEiJDfT+usLRsk5GAnm2sSAvycvMF+zQ0grCSN8UoShkgwOaMsYAmQig7D2P0bB8C76+CAA)

---

Edit: realized we don't need the actual string literal types, with just `string` values we can get rid of `_GetParseFieldResultValue` and still get:

```
type Z = {
    address: {
        city: string;
        state: string;
    };
} & {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}
```

[**Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglhANgEwAoCcD2YDOUC8UA3gFBRQB2AhgLYQBcUOw6cFA5gNxlQBuViAK4MmLNlx7oIAR0FwpyRgCNMmRBCoVu5ZiHU4A-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-tlODxckPkSs0xnBOZhbIEFo5jemCiCBYEDue5wYWH+u6uH+OKHmV+ARRUOg9MAFj9FA7mLGVMUzQ40A-H8yT0Od8QWM93yGhAxrvZ9lw-XSwAMkyH3NE9jG-TaENA7YIOOi6boQ8RUPxDtUTJPh2nJEKhBYzjWmEfjKXEN4NgY+QcBxTiZU7emuOEVEizCngX4-mBP6M8zjgEzGhRU9TSgoTOwvNNM1PuiEVBVh0CPkFjbMipzi7c4uO0C0dIqaCAEtQ6LGjiwjUuS59UjAII6AUTtwuzBT7NQAFlnQaxtHqVNfjNJb1sUfNjGLcxomI1dN3uQ+6APRUAyVVAWxiBwEf1V7Mw+EZYqmV1D4ACLGlQcAQqOAeu6WaVWV7YFQAAWqOGvJox6B52Dhc4NwPr1NmNe4SQHfNHzRGkH31NakJicSMPGMWiIwkGb3vqS+3voSfMk+hPIKxJPpE8L-EyzAJkM-j0vh4kEAA)

Comment: Very close (possibly as close as it gets?). Unfortunately, it's technically returning the type of the array structure, instead of the object it constructs/returns (unless you can return ` typeof ParseFieldsResult<T>` within the function). That said, I'll mark this as the answer at the end of this week if no other answers solve the issue. Nevertheless, thank you for your time and code!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, it is returning a value of the type `ParseFieldsResult<T>` (though the typing is a little sloppy inside the fn)

Comment: My bad, when I looked at the type, I assumed it was returning a typed array. However, as is, the returned object structure is still ambiguous. So, I'd essentially like to return the `typeof ParseFieldsResult<T>` within the function. See updated question above for updated playgrounds using your code.

Comment: On implementation with my project, this answer won't work as it makes the fields readonly. The fields are set to React state in a form and then updated dynamically.

Comment: Thinking about it, if the value of `name` changes (at runtime) then the type would need to change as well. I'm guessing when you go through a React state it will be impossible to do. Unless you find a way so it doesn't lose track of the `name` type values. -- Without that the `name` needs to still be `readonly` (though the rest can be mutable)

Comment: Only the `value` prop will change during runtime. Perhaps, I'll just create/utilize a readonly array string list of the `name` properties and then use those as static keys. While it does create more code, it should simplify some of the type logic. I'll try to take a stab at it over the weekend. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

On the parseFields function, you have a return type of K.. which is an empty object... shouldn't you be passing in FieldProps?

`const parseFields = <T extends any[], K extends object = {}>(fields: T): **FieldProps** => {`

Comment: Use backticks `\`` (or `\`\`\``) instead of quotes for code :)

Comment: This will return the wrong type. Instead of returning `FieldProps`, it should dynamically return an object of whatever string is in `name` as a property and apply `typeof value` to it, like so: `{ firstName: string, lastName: string, ...etc }`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a generic method here, and also setting K's default type to {}, that's why you are seeing {} during hover over.

You can achieve what you are looking for by calling the method properly.
Like this:

```
const userDetails = parseFields<FieldProps[], {
  "firstName": string,
  "lastName": string,
  "address": {
    "city": string,
    "state": string
  }
}>(fields);
```

Comment: This just overrides `T` and `K`. I want to dynamically assign `K` based upon what's present in `T` which should be set by argument `fields`. Also, since the function can build a dynamic object, I'm trying to avoid having to manually type it.

Comment: It is building a dynamic object but not a dynamic type, it is returning K which defaults to {}, so it will always typecast your result to {} unless you pass the K type to the function.

Comment: `K` is currently assigned to the accumulator `{}` within `reduce`, but no type. Also, tried assigning `K` to result of the `reduce`, but again, displays an empty object type.

Comment: K extends object = {} is basically the same thing as type K = {} and as your function’s return type is K, you will always get {}

Comment: You're absolutely right about the problem but this is an awful fix. By passing the return type, the whole function becomes a hidden type assertion.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Well, what you are asking for is building a dynamic type during runtime, which is not possible with typescript.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm asking for. It may not be possible to do what the OP wants.